# Using cookies in python requests doesn't login to the website

Tags: python

I use my own laptop's Google Chrome to login to a website a human, and I also use this Chrome's [extension](https://chromewebstore.google.com/detail/cookiemanager-cookie-edit/hdhngoamekjhmnpenphenpaiindoinpo) which gives me a json output of the website's cookies.

I save the cookies, and then save them in my server as `cookies.json`.

And I go to my server and run this python code (this is the whole code since now):

```py
import requests
import json

with open('cookies.json', 'r') as file:
    cookies_tmp = json.load(file)

cookies = cookies_tmp[0]

s = requests.get(url='https://www.example.com/myServices?t_page=1',
                 cookies=cookies)
```

But this is my error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/test/test/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/requests/api.py", line 73, in get
    return request("get", url, params=params, **kwargs)
  File "/home/test/test/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/requests/api.py", line 59, in request
    return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "/home/test/test/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 573, in request
    prep = self.prepare_request(req)
  File "/home/test/test/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 484, in prepare_request
    p.prepare(
  File "/home/test/test/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/requests/models.py", line 370, in prepare
    self.prepare_cookies(cookies)
  File "/home/test/test/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/requests/models.py", line 627, in prepare_cookies
    cookie_header = get_cookie_header(self._cookies, self)
  File "/home/test/test/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/requests/cookies.py", line 147, in get_cookie_header
    jar.add_cookie_header(r)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/http/cookiejar.py", line 1375, in add_cookie_header
    attrs = self._cookie_attrs(cookies)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/http/cookiejar.py", line 1334, in _cookie_attrs
    self.non_word_re.search(cookie.value) and version > 0):
TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object
```

Am I doing anything wrong? Aren't cookies enough to have access to a website?

Comment: Most systems return a session ID after a login request to you and your browser stores this value as a cookie and uses this cookie in subsequent requests. You need to set the session ID cookie in your request, too

Comment: @user70 I don't see such session ID in my Inspect Element, in the cookies.

Comment: Then you need a session ID, otherwise the website won't count you as logged in. Login from the browser and take the session ID value from inspect

Comment: @user70 what browser do you use? I cannot find such thing, and I'm googling but still no luck. I' even looking for the session ID in the Inspect in SO website but I cannot such thing for the Stackoverflow either.

Answer (score 0):

Try using a header cookie.

```
import requests
header = {
"Cookie": "SomeName=SomeValue;"
}
requests.get(url, headers=header)
```

BTW, this still does not guarantee that you will be logged in. Different websites have different ways to authenticate a user. Many may have some secondary checks with JavaScript.

So without thoroughly inspecting your client, it would be impossible to correctly answer your question.

Comment: Thanks, but it didn't work. I still see the email and password in `s.text`. It seems it doesn't say like `my JavaScript is not enabled`. It doesn't matter for this website to have JS enabled.